# Can Python be used together with hook-script in TortoiseSVN

Tags: c#, python, tortoisesvn, hook

I've written a static analysis tool in Python, which I'm using manually for new code I'm writing. But I'd like to implement it as a hook-script for TortoiseSVN every time i commit it, so it is run automatically. Problem is, that TortoiseSVN doesn't seem to support Python-scripts (all guides I found was written in C#).

Is there a fix for using Python together with TortoiseSVN without re-writing the Python to C#? It wouldn't be a problem, however time consuming.

Anyone with experience in implementing hook-scripts for TortoiseSVN *not* written in C#?

Comment: Of course that is possible, just make sure your script is marked as executable and has the necessary shebang in the first line. On the other hand, you seem to have a windows system...well.

Comment: It's Windows, yes. Is it still feasible, or would it be best to rewrite it in C#?

Comment: You would have to execute the script by executing python with the script as parameter. It should be possible, just a bit more elaborate than plain executable script with python shebang.

Comment: What about py2exe? I haven't used it before, though. I'll try with shebang, but shouldn't Windows already associate .py extensions with Python when installed? Please submit a summary of your answers as an 'answer' and I'll accept it.

Comment: Not sure my answer really is 100% valid. I don't have python in my win environment. Only use it on my macOS an Linux machines. But if what you cooked up based on my meager suggestions works, we can make up an answer together ;)